# program to count the numbers that are divisible by given number

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

OVERVIEW:  Given 2 integers (num1, num2), write a function that returns the count of numbers between the num1..num2 that are divisible by num1.
        E.g.: count(3, 15) returns 5 (3, 6, 9, 12, 15).
        Note : You need to consider Inclusive range
INPUTS:  Two numbers num1, num2.
        num1, num2 >= 0.

OUTPUT: Return the count of numbers between the num1..num2 that are divisible by num1.

ERROR CASES: Return -1 in error cases.
This is my code:

```
int count(int num1, int num2) {
     int temp;

    int i, j,k;

    i = num1;
    j = num2;
    temp = 0;
    for (k = 1; k <= j;k++)
    {
        if (k%i == 0)
            temp++;


    }

    return temp;

}
```

While running test case in visual studio only one test is passed and another test is not passed for testing.
The part I highlighted is the test which is failed.
(countzero testcase)

[image]
The following is the error which is thrown when i tried running it in tool.
[image]
Please help me

Comment: Don't post images of text. Read [ask].

Comment: The most helpful thing you can do is try to narrate to yourself, in words, what you think your code does for a couple of simple test cases.  If it's easier you can start with the failing test case.  You don't indicate what the failing case is, but let's try `count(9, 10)`.  I think the answer returned should be "0" but your implementation gets "1".  Walk through the code for when `num1` is 9 and `num2` is 10, step by step in your head.

Comment: I can not see your images. Anyway as you told you want to count numbers between inserted numbers but you start from 1 in the `for` loop. Your for loop should be as following: `for(k=num1;k<=num2;k++) {if(k%num1==0) temp++;}`

Comment: Your function will not return -1 if you don't test for those pesky error cases.  Worse, it may trigger a divide by zero error, or something like that.  And I don't see a loop that increments a counter from num1 to num2.  And what happens if num1 > num2 ?

Comment: My point is that you should start by checking for illegal inputs, handle these errors, and then your function will have a better chance of running smoothly, won't it?

Comment: You highlighted the test case that failed. Good, so we know the name of the test case. But don't you think we also need to know what the input was, what the desired output was, what are you getting?

Comment: The debugger _can_ show you the values of the local variables, you know.

Comment: If you're not obliged to use a loop, then `num2 / num1` gives you the answer you need.  (Test: (3, 15) = (15 / 3) = 5; (3, 16) = (16 / 3) = 5; (3, 17) = (17/3) = 5; (3, 18) = (18 / 3) = 6 — looks OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Here is the pseudo code of what was asked, compare to your function, add the missing parts, and it should pass the tests with no issues.

function (num1, num2), returns count

- check input is within stated range: num1 <= num2 ? num1, num2 >= 0 ?

  - if not, return -1
- we'll use %, check input to avoid divide by zero

  - if num1 == 0, return -1
- reset count
- loop for (i = num1; i <= num2; ++i)
- if i % num1 == 0, (should be safe, if all error cases are already covered)

  - ++count
- end loop
- return count.